# Gruntfile.js - Task “default” not found while implementing sass

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: ['sass/**/*.{scss,sass}','sass/_partials/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['sass']
            },
            livereload: {
                files: ['*.html', '*.php', 'js/**/*.{js,json}', 'css/*.css','img/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },
        sass: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                outputStyle: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'css/styles.css': 'sass/styles.scss'
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
}
```

couldn't find what's wrong anymore in my gruntfile.js, it gave me an error of Task “default” not found, what's wrong?

Comment: In my own gruntfiles, I put the 'registerTask' lines below 'loadNpmTasks' lines to make sure everything is loaded before I use them. Maybe it would help to move the 'registerTask' line to the end?

Comment: No. I solved this problem, I remove my commented code above and it worked. Strange.